# Cannot connect Java to external mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

Hello i am currently building a programm that register users to mysql database. Everything works fine on localhost but when i try to connect to external database it gives me an error such as this below.

[image]

I have granted all privileges to the user in the database i am trying to acess and also i have the driver installed. Any ideas??

My code:

```
private void createEventListenerDBProperties() {
        dbSubmitBtn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                if (dbDriverChooser.getSelectedItem().equals("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")) {
                  driver = (String) dbDriverChooser.getSelectedItem();
                  port = dbPortField.getText();
                  host = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostField.getText() + ":" + port + "/";
                  db = dbnameField.getText();
                  dbuser = dbUsernameField.getText();
                  dbpassword = new String(dbPasswordField.getPassword());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Connection instanciateDB() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host + db, dbuser, dbpassword);
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection not Established");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Project2.this, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Comment: You should try to check the connectivity to the remote host on desired port. Try to telnet on the remote port

Comment: it gives me the same error in 2 ports i have checked right now and both are available for connectivity both 3306 and 3536. so i dont think thats the reason

Comment: Typical mysql configuration often sets up `username@localhost` meaning mysql will not allow the user to connect from remote addresses, so ensure you've setup `username@*`.  That being said, the error you show is more indicative of tcp ip issues, so try `telnet [your host] 3306` at command prompt (dos or *nix will work) and make sure you can connect.  Note that the model you're trying to do (local app connects to remote mysql) is not generally advisable, those types of connections are not encrypted and should generally occur over a trusted network only (e.g. a LAN).

Comment: @KostasMatrix You've checked two ports (and they're both available for connectivity?) Awesome. Try the port mysql is configured to listen on. It will be singular and it will be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think your way to connect is wrong. Instead of this:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host + db, dbuser, dbpassword);
```

try this:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host + db + "?user=" +  dbuser + "&password=" +dbpassword);
```

Check this out, it may be useful. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html